# Unknown/Inconsistent sort behaviour on arrays in Google chrome

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-chrome, sorting

I am not able to understand the below mentioned behavior while sorting an array, in Google chrome. It seems to be inconsistent. I tried the same in Internet explorer and Mozilla Firefox, it seemed working fine. Can anyone please help me understand and resolve the issue.

EDIT:
The requirement is to sort a list of objects based on a criteria. This list of objects is bound to List view on the UI. The criteria to sort can be equal for any two objects in the list. When the objects are equal, and the sorting is applied on the list, the list order behaves inconsistently. Below is the piece of code to reproduce this behavior.

```
--Creating the array 
x=[{Name:'h1', value: 1},{Name:'h2', value: 1},{Name:'h3', value: 1},{Name:'h4', value: 1},{Name:'h5', value: 1},{Name:'h6', value: 1},{Name:'h7', value: 1},{Name:'h8', value: 1},{Name:'h9', value: 1},{Name:'h10', value: 1},{Name:'h11', value: 1},{Name:'h12', value: 1},{Name:'h13', value: 1}]

--Sort the array
x.sort(function (a, b) {a = a.value;b = b.value;if (a < b)return -1;if (a > b) return 1; return 0;})    
--Results in order, 
--h7, h1, h3, h4, h5, h6, h2, h8, h9, h10, h11, h12, h13

--Sort the array again
x.sort(function (a, b) {a = a.value;b = b.value;if (a < b)return -1;if (a > b) return 1; return 0;})
--Results in order, 
--h2, h7, h3, h4, h5, h6, h1, h8, h9, h10, h11, h12, h13
```

Comment: You have an array of object so you need to implement you own sorting algorithm. `sort()` is designed to work on base types (string, int etc)

Comment: I tried to use x.sort(function(a, b){return 0;}), defining how to compare the objects. Still I am getting the same result?

Comment: What order are you attempting to achieve?

Comment: When there is a definitive order, the sort works fine, but when the values I derive to be equal using my comparer, the sort returns different values each time I sort. This sorted list is bound to the UI, so each time I sort even though they are equal and no change, the list changes. This is not what we are looking for.

Comment: It's default behavior. If you use sort and don't tell it what the proper order is, it becomes kinda-random (but not really -- as in you should not use it to randomize an array, because it's not). You will have to come up with a way to tell the sorter how to behave - you mention wanting to sort the array on two properties.

Comment: I'm guessing you want to order the list to pull whatever it is that was selected to the top -- that's more like filtering than sort. The default sort can only order the entire array up- or down.

Answer (score 0):

Returning 0 from a sorting comparison means that the objects are 'the same'. Return -1 or 1 to tell the sorting function what to do with it.

Since you're not sorting an array of strings or numbers, but objects, you need to tell the sorter what property to use for the sorting.

```
.sort(function (a, b){
  if (a.Name < b.Name) { 
    return -1;
  };
  if (a.Name > b.Name) {
    return 1;
  };
  // Return 0, or decide to compare on something else.
  return 0;
});
```

This will result in 'h1, h10, h11, ...', because of the way strings are compared. If you want to sort it like a number, h1, h2, h3, you'll need to do some extra work before comparing:

```
var result = x.sort(function (a, b){
    var anumber = parseInt(a.Name.substring(1));
    var bnumber = parseInt(b.Name.substring(1));
  if (anumber < bnumber) { 
    return -1;
  };
  if (anumber > bnumber) {
    return 1;
  };
  // Return 0, or decide to compare on something else.
  return 0;
});
```

This results in the array being sorted 'h1, h2, h3, ...'. There's more ways to go about doing this, but this is one.

Comment: I have edited the question, please have a look. I am looking for the reason, why the inconsistent behavior when the item values are compared to be equal?